# Rollover Button inside JQuery Tools Tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, rollover

I have a rollover image 125x80. The following code is simple html&css and works ok, but when I try to integrate the #questions div inside a JQuery Tools Tab Pane, the button never appears. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

#questions a:link{
height: 40px;
width: 125px;
display: block; 
background: url(../images/btn-questions.png) no-repeat left top;
}

#questions a:hover{  background-position: left bottom;  }   

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="questions"> <a href="#"></a> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

That's works. Then I try to integrate it in JQuery Tools Tab Pane, the following way:

```
<div class="panes"> 

<div>
This is the first tab. This text appears inside the pane
<img src="../This image works too.png" />

<div id="questions">
    <a href="#">WHY THIS ROLLOVER BUTTON DOESN'T APPEAR INSIDE THE PANE?</a>
</div>

</div>  
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I gave up with JQuery Tools Tabs. It seems too complicated to me. Now I'm using the tabs from http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/tabs/ and the rollover image works ok. Also, I had to change the CSS by the following:

```
#questions {
position: absolute;
left:500px;
top:75px;
width:125px; 
height:40px;        
overflow:hidden; /* IE needed */     
}

#questions a:hover img
{ margin-top:-40px }
```

And I changed the div by:

```
<div id="questions">  
    <a href="#"><img  src="../images/btn-questions.png" ></a>
</div>
```

I prefer this tab. Also, you don't need any image for the tabs as JQuery Tools requires. Much better, clean, and easy. Hope this solution can help to anyone with the same problem.